# Displaying remote sensing imagery on GEE using Folium maps

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, google-earth-engine-python-api, evi, google-colab

I am a novice GEE user, and am just getting started with analyzing satellite data using the Python API on Google Colab. I have successfully imported MODIS data and am displaying it using Folium, but am having trouble figuring out how to clip it to only display data within a certain AOI.  Code attached-- why is the .filterBounds() not working to clip the selected MODIS data?  It is showing EVI for the entire US when I scroll out.

```
import ee
import folium

# Trigger the authentication flow.
ee.Authenticate()

# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize(project='ee-modistesting')

#Dates for imagery acquisition
i_date = '2020-01-01'
f_date = '2020-12-30'

#AOI covering most of Alabama
my_AOI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([33, -87,
                                   31, -85])

#Fetching MODIS Terra daily EVI as ee Image Collection
lc = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MOD09GA_006_EVI")

#Filter date and select EVI band
lc = lc.filterDate(i_date, f_date).filterBounds(my_AOI)
lc = lc.select("EVI")

#EVI parameters
evi_parameters = {'min': 0,
                   'max': 1,
                   'dimensions': 512,
                   'palette': [
                      'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
                      '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
                      '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
                    ],
                   'region': my_AOI}

# Display the image using folium
my_map = folium.Map(location=[32.217464733260854, -88.05273443493647], zoom_start=12)
my_map.addLayer(lc,evi_parameters)
my_map
```

Answer (score 0):

`filterBounds()` filters your image collection. If an image intersects the provided bounds, it will be retained. In this case, the MODIS images are really big, covering a significantly larger area than your AOI. To remove everything but your AOI fro the map, you can `clip()`. You can only do that on an image though, and `lc` is an image collection. You have to reduce the collection to a single image, for instance by taking the median value of all pixels:

```
composite = (lc
  .median() # Take the median value for each pixel
  .clip(my_AOI) # Mask out all pixels outside your AOI
)
```